# Hacked E-Cigs meaning

Tags: word-meaning

What does "hack" mean in this sentence

> **Hacked E-Cigs** May Get around Regulations.

I looked up the dictionary but didn't find appropriate definition.

Source:[Scientificamerican](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode/hacked-e-cigs-may-get-around-regulations1/)

Comment: The subtitle of the article gives the meaning. Plus, have you never heard of hacking into a computer to modify the contents of that computer? Suggestion: look up "hack" as a noun and then apply it as a past-participle adjective. Or: look in a different dictionary.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I just didn't think of that usage. Thanks!

Comment: Which dictionary did you use?

Comment: Some online dictionaries, for example: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hack

Comment: Dictionaries seem not to define *hack* precisely for this usage; however, they seem to define something really close, but more restricted to the context of computer systems and information technology. To me, when something is hacked (in this sense), it usually means that that thing is modified in an unintended manner, usually an unauthorized modification.

Comment: @CYC Mostly from other posts on this site, I've found Collins and Longmans online dictionaries to be helpful, also Oxford Advanced American dictionary. I mean, if you can't find it in one, check another or two. :).

Comment: @DamkerngT. modified in an _unintended_ manner? Is that what computer hackers are doing? I thought that computer hackers have been making intended modifications of computer contents/databases. Also, if either/both the subtitle and sentences in the article itself gives an explanatory sentence, that's something else for a langauge learner to learn to pick up on to improve one's language skills.

Comment: @CarSmack Obviously, it wasn't the best phrase I said in my life. So thank you for the correction. :) However, I think it shouldn't be too difficult to read "using/modifying a thing (usually a tool or a device) in an unintended manner" as "using/modifying that thing (or that tool or that device) for its unintended purpose--abusing it". I can't say for sure if this usage is common enough for everyone (it's common enough for me); for example, hammering a screw into its socket would be qualified as a "hacking", imo. When a device is abused in a similar way, saying that it's hacked is fine to me.

Comment: Headline writers often like to embed puns, so there's a chance that "Hack" in this context is also intentionally meant to allude to a _hacking cough_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "hacked" part in the hacked e-cig means modified.